# Calculate consumed power/energy in discrete metering

Tags: power, measurement, energy

Suppose I measure power consumption after each 1sec interval, and it is assumed that in between the interval, the power consumption of is same as of previously (`n-1`th second) measured value. For example, I have the following table:

```
nth sec              power measured (W)
~~~~~~~              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1                    12
2                    15
3                    45
4                    12
5                    42
6                    78
7                    51
8                    13
9                    23
10                   07
```

Then what is the total energy consumption?

Comment: Sum them as W seconds Ws, then convert to Wh or kWh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy consumed will be the power x time (where time is the interval since the last reading). In this case it is watts x seconds so each reading will be in Ws.

To convert to Wh you divide by 3600.

To convert to kWh you divide the above answer by a further 1000.

> after each 1 sec interval, and it is assumed that in between the interval, the power consumption of is same as of previously (n-1th second) measured value.

You haven't quite worded this correctly. I think you mean to say that the sampling plan takes the end-of-period power to be the average power for that period. That's fine if the power changes relatively slowly.

Comment: The last reading was not for a 10 second duration though, it was at the 10th second so all readings are * 1 ...

Comment: Correct. I've clarified that in the first sentence in case there was any confusion.

Comment: Correct. I've clarified that in the first sentence in case there was any confusion.

Comment: So, for the example shown, total power consumption of 10 sec duration is 298Ws or 298 Joule or 298/3600=0.083Wh or .00008 unit. Thanks for the clarifications. Just another ask, what if the interval is 2sec or 10ms? Is it: (12*2+15*2+...)Ws, (12*10/1000 +15*10/1000)Ws?

Comment: That's correct. If your example number are representative then you have fairly wild variation within your sampling period. This would suggest that your sampling frequency isn't high enough.